# Wordpress: Is it possible to access admin Panel if you have the database info

Tags: php, wordpress

hello I have the database credentials of my Wordpress site saved in my pc. The problem is I lost the cpanel credentials. I don't know the administrator Password too. I want to know is it possible to retrieve user info or is it possible to create new user from the database credentials which I have so I can access the admin Panel

Comment: Contact your host. Your question doesn't seem to meet the requirements for SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

If your old (database) server supports remote MySQL connections, you can install Wordpress on a new host using database credentials from your old server. In other words, Wordpress on the new server will use the database on the one.

Then you can do anything you want with your database (e.g. add/remove users).